# R - expect_equal. Only print cases which break tolerance

Tags: r, testthat

I am using the R function expect_equal to test if two large vectors are equal (almost) up to a certain tolerance. I was wondering if there was a way to only print the cases where expect_equal breaks the tolerance.

For example

```
a <- c(2.001, 3.5)
b <- c(2,3)

expect_equal(object=a,expected=b,tolerance=0.015, scale=1).
```

This prints the error:

```
Error: c(2, 3) not equal to c(2.001, 3.5)
2/2 mismatches (average diff: 0.25).
```

First 2:

```
pos x y  diff    
1 2 2.0 -0.001    
2 3 3.5 -0.500
```

Even though case 1 "passes" my test. Is it possible to only print the cases that break the tolerance level? And even better would be if I could then  store and refer to cases which fail so that I can route out the errors quicker.

Comment: One way to do this is to create a new vector or even column on the table to hold whether they break the tolerance level. This way, you can refer to it later and then print out what you need through a function that is called on only the entries that do not fit your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is "no".  You can't only show the values that break the tolerance.  The reason is that equality is tested using the "all.equal" function which doesn't have that option (to see this, you can look at the function "compare.numeric" in testthat via

```
testthat:::compare.numeric
```

at the R command prompt.

The longer answer depends how hard you want to work to get your answer and how often you will reuse the method.  The simplest is to do as @VermillionAzure mentioned, manually generate the vector out of tolerance and check for its length to be 0 (or a similar test).  For that test, you could use the expect_true function.  A more complex method would be to create your own data class (other than numeric) and then make your own compare method for that class.  If you really need the result to be summarized your way, you may have to go down the path of creating your own compare function.

For the second part of your question (storing to refer to tests that failed later), you can store the results of the test() function call from testthat, and from that, you can find what function had the errors.

```
results <- test()
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, for a temp solution I quickly built my own (pretty poor) test but this is a much nicer solution. Thank you @VermillionAzure as well for your help.

Comment: all.equal has a tolerance arg. thanks for mentioning it.